# How to find a position in a list determined by another list? PYTHON

Tags: python, list

So i'm trying to do a function were given you `lis1=[1,2,6,8,10]`, `lis2=['earth', 'sky', 'village', 'line', 'tree', 'lake', 'beach', 'dock', 'earth', 'sky', 'beach', 'eyes', 'village']` `string='beach'`

I have to find the string `"beach"` in the `list 2` in the positions given by the `list1`

I found that I can see in the `list2` with the position given by the `list1` doing this, for example

```
def properties(w,z,y):
  loki=[]
  if y in z[w[1]]:
    loki.append(w[1])
```

But I need to do it automatically cause I can't know if the `list1` will be 5 positions long or will be 16, is there any way to do it?

I tried with a for loop but I only get that the list searches in the first position, but then will start from there in the next position so the index will be out of range

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: What is `w,z,y`. And length of `lis1` n `lis2` are not same, so how can you check

Answer (score 1):

```
lis1=[1,2,6,8,10,150,9,15,25]
lis2=['earth', 'sky', 'village', 'line', 'tree', 'lake', 'beach', 'dock', 'earth', 'sky', 'beach', 'eyes', 'village']
string = "beach"

res = [idx for idx in lis1 if (idx<len(lis2) and lis2[idx] == string)]

print(res)

res: [6,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for position in lis1:
    if lis2[position] == string:
        print(f'found {string} at {position}')
        break
```

This will iterate through `lis1` that contains the indices to be searched and will then check `lis2` at the index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try. You also need to check for index errors if the list index is not found.

```
lis1=[1,2,6,8,10]
lis1.sort()
lis2=['earth', 'sky', 'village', 'line', 'tree', 'lake', 'beach', 'dock', 'earth', 'sky', 'beach', 'eyes', 'village'] 
string='beach'
for i in lis1:
    try:
        if lis2[i]==string:
            print(f"Found '{string}' at position '{i}'")
            
    except IndexError:
        print("List length is too short for checking")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
lis1 = [-100, "3", 1, 78.9, None, 2, 6, 8, 10, 100]
lis2 = ['earth', 'sky', 'village', 'line', 'tree', 'lake', 'beach', 'dock', 'earth', 'sky', 'beach', 'eyes', 'village']
a_string = 'beach'

pos_found = sorted(set(lis1).intersection([i for i, v in enumerate(lis2) if v == a_string]))
print(f'"{a_string}" was found at {pos_found}')
```

Output:

```
"beach" was found at [6, 10]
```